# A direct way to turn bits according to mask

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit

Suppose we have a byte `B` and a mask `M` such that one of the bits in the mask is either 1 or 0 and the others are 0, (suppose we know which bit that is, it can be any bit but for simplicity it's the LSB). We want that the same bit in `B` will have the same value as that bit from `M`.

For example if `B=1111`, `M=0000` then we want to have after the operation `B=1110`, but if `M` was `M=0001` then `B` would have been `B=1111`.

I'm basically asking how to implement the boolean function generated from this truth table:

```
old new result
0   0   0
0   1   1
1   0   0
1   1   1
```

So `result` would be:

```
a=old, b= new
result=a'b+ab
```

Doing `B = ~B&M | B&M;` in C doesn't seem to work...

I probably can do it with conditionals but there's got to be a way to it without them.

Another example:
If we care about the second bit, and if `B=0001`, `M=0010` then the result of the operation would be `0011`. But if `M` was `M=0000` then the result of the operation was `0001`.

I know how to set clear and toggle a bit, this is not what I'm asking.

Comment: I'm confused, based on your truth table, `f` is identical to `new`

Comment: I think it's a coincidence that they're identical. @vu1p3n0x Let's call it `result` instead of `f`.

Comment: @kuhaku Give better examples or a concise algorithm then please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you set, clear and toggle a single bit in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c-c)

Comment: I'm also confused by the example, if `input = 1111` and `mask = 0000` how is `output = 1110` after the operation? In my book `input = 1111` with `mask = 0000` should be `output = 0000`, and for example `input = 1101` with `mask = 0111` has `output = 0101`. Just use the bit-wise & operator.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ok I'll write more examples.

Comment: @JohanWentholt Only one of the bits in the mask is to be considered, the others (which will be 0) should be ignored.

Comment: `~B&M | B&M` is a funny way to write `M`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I undestand correctly, you want to set a single bit from B to the value of that bit in M, and you don't care what the previous value in B was. M is not really a mask in this case; your mask is given by the bit number. So you'd do something like

```
unsigned mask = (1<<BITNUM);
unsigned result = (~mask & B) | (mask & M)
```

where BITNUM = 0 if it's the LSB.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the offset to the bit you care about (e.g. `index`):

```
char AssignBit(unsigned char byte, unsigned char mask, int index)
{
    unsigned char cleared = byte & ~(1 << index);
    unsigned char assigned = cleared | mask & (1 << index);
    return assigned;

    // or simply:
    return byte & ~(1 << index) | mask & (1 << index);

    // if it is guaranteed that at most one bit is set in mask, this also works:
    return byte & ~(1 << index) | mask;
}
```

Comment: The code can invoke undefined behaviour because of shifting signed integers and changing the sign bit. OP uses unsigned types - hopefully intentionally.

Comment: @Olaf I'm assuming `index` is a valid index for a 8-bit byte, i.e. in the range `0..7`. If this condition is satisfied, there is no UB.

Comment: `char` is a byte, but there is no guarantee it has 8 bits. There are very well architectures with 16-bit bytes.

Comment: @Olaf Fine, `index` must be in the range `0..CHAR_BIT-1` and `MAX_INT` must be greater than `CHAR_BIT`. I highly doubt there exists a platform where this is not satisfied.

Comment: I already told you they exist. There's more to processors than x86 and ARM!

Comment: @Olaf I believe there exists platform for which `CHAR_BIT != 8` but certainly not `CHAR_BIT >= MAX_INT`.

Comment: There is even no platform with `CHAR_BIT >= MAX_INT / 128`. But there are platforms with `SCHAR_MAX == MAX_INT`, i.e. with `int` and `char` having the same bitwidth.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be implemented as a boolean function, as the operators you want to use are bit-wise, and so the operands are multi-bit. But you can incorporate some bit-shifts to accommodate that:

```
#define BIT_NUMBER   3  // For example

B &= ~(1 << BIT_NUMBER); // Zero out the bit
B |= M << BIT_NUMBER; // Set to M's bit value
```

Answer (score 1):

> For example if B=1111, M=0000 then we want to have after the operation
>   B=1110

The problem is that you haven't specified which bit in `M` is significant, and there's no way to determine the significant bit from the value of `M`.

---

You actually need three quantities, the byte `B`, the value `V` (which you're calling M), and a mask `M` (which is missing from your question).

Here's the code that combines the three:

```
result = (B & ~M) | (V & M);
```

Answer (score -1):

How to change the `n`th bit to `x`:

```
number ^= (-x ^ number) & (1 << n);
```

(Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/47990/6149078)